# How To Refer To The `main` Field Value Inside of package.json?

Tags: javascript, json, npm, terminal, package.json

Inside of one's [*package.json*](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json), it's customary to specify the primary (or *main*) entry point of your module by including a file path (relative to the project's root) as the value for [the `main` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main).

Likewise, there is [the `scripts` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#scripts), a dictionary whose keys are keywords allowing one to run the associated command passed as its value inside of the terminal. One such commonly seen script allows you to run Node or [Nodemon](https://nodemon.io/). For illustration, here's an example *package.json* config:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Example package.json for StackOverflow question",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "IsenrichO",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.1"
  }
}
```

You'll  notice the `dev` script command in the above runs [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/) on the *index.js* file. This file is also the application's entry point as specified in the `main` field.

My question, then: Is it possible to refer to the file specified by the *package.json*'s `main` key inside of one of your `scripts`? In other words, could one write something like

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon main"
  }
```

It seems pedantic, but is a genuine question. Appreciate all help!

Comment: From what I read, https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts, it seems scripts is looking for some sort of executable file. Before having read the documentation, my initial thought was, and seems correct, that nodemon main would try to run a file called main in your root directory (for the project), such as running nodemon main from the command line would likely look for and run main.js (if it existed) or throw an error (if main.js didn't exist). Perhaps someone else has more insight on this than I.

Answer (score 5):

I believe nodemon takes your `main` script by default so you can just use `"dev": "nodemon"`.

However: you can refer to your `package.json`'s keys with variables using `$npm_package_KEY`.

In your case:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon $npm_package_main"
}
```

Child properties like: `$npm_package_author_name`

On windows you need to remove the `$` and wrap the variable in `%`:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon %npm_package_main%"
}
```

Comment: The keys need to be in "config" https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#config . For me, it did not work otherwise.